# JavaScript to format account number

Tags: javascript

I have to format an account number input field like below:

**Desired format:** `123456 1234 12 1`

[image]

But, the regex which I wrote formats the text field as below:

**Current format:** `1234 1234 1234 1`

Can someone please help me with the correct regex or logic to implement this?

```js
function cc_format(value) {
  var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
  var matches = v.match(/\d{4,13}/g);
  var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
  var parts = []
  for (i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i += 4) {
    parts.push(match.substring(i, i + 4))
  }
  if (parts.length) {
    return parts.join(' ')
  } else {
    return value
  }
}

onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('account-number').oninput = function() {
    this.value = cc_format(this.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>AccountNumber</div><br/>
  <input id="account-number" value="" placeholder="123456 1234 12 1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get groups of 6, instead of groups of 4, then, as soon as your second group gets over 4 characters long, you can insert a space at the desired position. Here's a proof of concept:

```js
function cc_format(value) {
  var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
  var matches = v.match(/\d{6,13}/g);
  var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
  var parts = []
  for (i = 0, len = match.length; i < len; i += 6) {
    parts.push(match.substring(i, i + 6))
  }
  if (parts.length > 1 && parts[1].length > 4) {
    parts[1] = [parts[1].slice(0, 4), ' ', parts[1].slice(4)].join('');
  }
  if (parts.length) {
    return parts.join(' ')
  } else {
    return v
  }
}

onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('account-number').oninput = function() {
    this.value = cc_format(this.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>AccountNumber</div><br/>
  <input id="account-number" value="" placeholder="123456 1234 12 1">
</form>
```

A **slightly more elegant solution** would be to use `.slice()` and `.join()` for the whole thing, which cleans up the code nicely. Here's an example:

```js
function cc_format(value) {
  var v = value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
  if (v.length > 6)
    v = [v.slice(0, 6), ' ', v.slice(6)].join('');
  if (v.length > 11)
    v = [v.slice(0, 11), ' ', v.slice(11)].join('');
  if (v.length > 14)
    v = [v.slice(0, 14), ' ', v.slice(14)].join('');
  if (v.length > 16)
    v = v.slice(0, 16);
  return v;
}

onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('account-number').oninput = function() {
    this.value = cc_format(this.value)
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>AccountNumber</div><br/>
  <input id="account-number" value="" placeholder="123456 1234 12 1">
</form>
```

Comment: @Durga, right. It's now returning `v` instead of `value` in case it has not yet exceeded the length required to add spacing.

Comment: loved your "elegant solution" +1.

Comment: Thank you @Anna! If this or any other solution helped you solve your problem, remember to mark one as accepted using the little tick mark under the question score.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, to format the code properly when user is typing. It works dynamically.

```js
const normalize = elem => {
  let value = elem.target.value;
  
  const onlyNums = value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');

  if (onlyNums.length <= 6) {
    return onlyNums;
  } else if (onlyNums.length <= 10) {
    return `${onlyNums.slice(0, 6)} ${onlyNums.slice(6)}`;
  } else if (onlyNums.length <= 12) {
    return `${onlyNums.slice(0, 6)} ${onlyNums.slice(6, 10)} ${onlyNums.slice(10, 12)}`;
  }
  return `${onlyNums.slice(0, 6)} ${onlyNums.slice(6, 10)} ${onlyNums.slice(10, 12)}
 ${onlyNums.slice(12, 13)}`;
 
};

const input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => e.target.value = normalize(e));
```

```html
<input type='text' id='input' value=''>
```